# Get IllegalStateException: Fragment already added

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin, fragment, illegalstateexception

Got the following error:

```
Caused by java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment already added: f{83e932d #2 f}
       at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment + 1916(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1916)
       at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps + 765(BackStackRecord.java:765)
       at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps + 2625(FragmentManagerImpl.java:2625)
       at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether + 2411(FragmentManagerImpl.java:2411)
       at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute + 2366(FragmentManagerImpl.java:2366)
       at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions + 2273(FragmentManagerImpl.java:2273)
       at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController.execPendingActions + 391(FragmentController.java:391)
       at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onResume + 517(FragmentActivity.java:517)
       at com.mandarine.sai.features.main.MainActivity.onResume + 73(MainActivity.java:73)
       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume + 1259(Instrumentation.java:1259)
       at android.app.Activity.performResume + 6408(Activity.java:6408)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity + 3116(ActivityThread.java:3116)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity + 3158(ActivityThread.java:3158)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage + 1404(ActivityThread.java:1404)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage + 102(Handler.java:102)
       at android.os.Looper.loop + 148(Looper.java:148)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main + 5458(ActivityThread.java:5458)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run + 738(ZygoteInit.java:738)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main + 628(ZygoteInit.java:628)
```

And here is my code in `MainActivity` :

```
 override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        this.applyPreferenceLocale()
    }
```

Line 73: super.onResume()

Comment: Before there something there's a fragment transaction being made, attempting to add a fragment that is already added. `super.onResume()` is just executing your pending fragment transactions.

Comment: @laalto is there a problem with the method of adding a fragment or replacing it?

Comment: @laalto not clear where does activity.
And the problem in General.

Comment: There can be many reasons for this, some quite hard to reproduce. Anyway all I say with the info here is that "fragment already added". Try to reproduce this crash yourself, and see what fragment transactions were involved before it.